# How can I add a rented resource to MS Project?

Tags: ms-project, resources, cost-management

I need to create a new resource that include a pay per day and quantity parameters.

For example, I have a resource "Rented Car - Type 1" with 60€/Day as daily cost.

In my project, I have a task (10 Days long) that requires 5 rented cars.
I need MS project to tell me that the total cost of this task is 10*5*60=3000€.

When the task duration changes, the cost will change automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1. Project Calendar is Standard (5d x 8h)
2. Fixed-units task w/ no task calendar.
3. RentalCar Work Resource w/ Std. and OT rates of 60 EUR/day. (Since this is a rental car, the resource calendar should be 7d x 8h.)
4. Assign RentalCar to task at 500%.
5. Assign Drivers (resource r1) to task at 500% (these guys work 5 days/wk).
6. Note because a 7dx8h resource is assigned, the task adopts the 7dx8h calendar.
   Rental car cost @ 10d duration is 3,000 EUR.
   Rental car cost @ 15d duration is 4,500 EUR.